# What is the risk of installing Visual C++ Redistributable Packages on Windows Production Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis

We are running lot of production applications in Windows Server 2012. Now one of our application requires Visual C++ Redistributable https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784. I don't wanna my production running application affected. I mostly running IIS/ASP.NET application with .NET framework 4.6. So, is there any risk of installing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply speaknig: If you dont ahve any app running that uses VC++ Redist then you install it and the other apps STILL DO NOT USE IT.

Any new application will use the most current installed major version.

Low risk. To be super sure - test out in a VM.

Comment: thanks installed and didn't found any issue :)